# Group by and flatten array of objects to match desired format

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

I have an array of objects like so:

```
{
 { HRProfile: 'Officer1', country: 'DEU', qty: 1 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer1', country: 'AUT', qty: 3 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer2', country: 'CZE', qty: 1 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer3', country: 'DEU', qty: 1 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer2', country: 'AUT', qty: 4 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer1', country: 'CZE', qty: 1 },
}
```

I want to present the data in the following manner:

```
Profile name | AUT| CZE| DEU | .... | Total
-------------------------------------------
Officer1     | 3  |  1 | 1   | ...  | 5
Officer2     | 4  |  1 | 0   | ...  | 5
Officer3     | 0  |  0 | 1   | ...  | 1
```

(values below are taken from 'qty' field)

I can use group-by on HRProfile and country to achieve a nested structure similar to this:

```
'Officer1':
{
 'DEU':
  {
  { HRProfile: 'Officer1', country: 'DEU', qty: 1 },
  ...
  },
  'AUT':
  {
  ...
  }
},
'Officer2':
{
...
}
```

But I still have to flatten this in a specific manner, to achieve aggregates for specific countries. Any help with this? Or perhaps there is a better approach for processing this?

Comment: What about a simple `map` that populates the `countryName1` and `countryName2` over each object? Or two getters. The input format seems to be already close to the desired result, I personally wouldn't group anything.

Comment: where are the country names from? please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Your desired nested structure doesn't make sense (ie. it's a broken representation). What is the value at path `'63'.'377'`? It's not an object, nor an array. Fix this to get any sensible kind of answer.

Comment: I have added more clarifications to the examples

Comment: I have added additional clarifications

Comment: @n0e that's incoherent, shouldn't Officer1 total be 5? 1+3+1...?

Comment: @briosheje you're right, my mistake, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired output format is still quite vague to me, though the below code should give you the table-like representation you're looking for.

Below code will group by HRProfile first and will acquire all the countries entries to later create an array of objects, where each object has the desired country key, the total value and `0` default value for missing countries.

This is a weird output format, though.

```js
const sampleData = [
 { HRProfile: 'Officer1', country: 'DEU', qty: 1 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer1', country: 'AUT', qty: 3 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer2', country: 'CZE', qty: 1 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer3', country: 'DEU', qty: 1 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer2', country: 'AUT', qty: 4 },
 { HRProfile: 'Officer1', country: 'CZE', qty: 1 },
];

let countries = {};
const grouped = sampleData.reduce((acc, next) => {
  acc[next.HRProfile] = acc[next.HRProfile] || {};
  acc[next.HRProfile][next.country] = next.qty;
  // Keep track of all the countries.
  countries[next.country] = 0;
  acc[next.HRProfile].total = (acc[next.HRProfile].total || 0) + next.qty;
  return acc;
}, {});

const tableLike = Object.entries(grouped).map(([HRProfile, data]) => {
  return Object.assign({HRProfile}, countries, data);
});

console.log(grouped);
console.log(tableLike);
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed. I owe you a beer.

Comment: @n0e thanks but I unluckily don't drink alcoholics :P Anyway, I suggest you to rethink about the data-model, it's a quite expensive and hard to mantain routine, you should think about other ways to elaborate your input, or use other approaches to render the values, otherwise, on the long run, you may encounter issues with further data elaboration ;).

Comment: I have a question, as you can see in the following sample [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bwv2c5Lr/) there is a problem with sum for individual columns (total is fine). I have a hard time trying to figure out how to change this code.

Comment: @n0e this is because the original constraint of having a single itemName is broken. The routine assigns the qty assuming there will be only a single itemName. To rapidly fix the issue, you should just increase the counter value of that item specifically if it's met again, working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/e25gqLx8/1/.